# Fibres of a Hurewicz fibration are homotopic equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, fibration, homotopy-extension-property

Can someone provide me a proof or a reference of the fact that fibres of a Hurewicz fibration $E \to B $ are homotopic equivalent for a path-connected space $B$. This question has been asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330508/homotopy-equivalence-of-fibres-of-a-hurewicz-fibration), but I am not convinced with the answer. For instance uniqueness of lifting is assumed which is not true for fibrations.

Comment: If you delete the uniqueness in the link, doesn't the argument still go through?

Comment: What precisely are your doubts with the linked answer?

Comment: One of the issues would be that the map $\tilde{h}$ won't be well defined since I have to make a choice for the lift of the path.

Comment: But $\overline{h}$ is the desired homotopy, and it need not be unique to get the result.